# Emberjs action model doesnt initialize new model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, ember-router

i have the following ember application http://jsfiddle.net/yw5cg/3/

it consists of two parts. One where the a list of "entries" is shown, and a view where new entries are entered.

if i populate the "entries" view via the entriesRoute using an array, and then press the button to go to the "new entry" view, i get a **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Person' of undefined**

however i comment out these lines in the EntriesRoute it transitions just fine :

```
  arr.pushObject(App.Entry.create({ UID: 1, Person: { Name: 'MoreTest', Street: 'TestVej' }, Controller: { CheckBox1: true, CheckBox2: false, CheckBox3: true, Dropdown: 'Mulighed2' } }));
  arr.pushObject(App.Entry.create({ UID: 2, Person: { Name: 'MoreTest', Street: 'TestVej' }, Controller: { CheckBox1: true, CheckBox2: false, CheckBox3: true, Dropdown: 'Mulighed2' } }));
```

i can not figure out why it does that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

my model object was defined as follows :

```
App.Entry = Ember.Object.extend({//snipped out});
```

apparently ember uses uppercase start letter in model objects as some way as defining a "master object",according to http://www.appliness.com/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-ember-js/, so if i change the above model to :

```
    App.entry = Ember.Object.extend({//snipped out});
```

it works